# qtip2 display issues on Webkit Browsers

Tags: jquery, webkit, qtip2

I'm using the qtip2 library to render tooltips, and recently I've been having issues where the tool tip does not display properly on Webkit browsers.  Firefox works perfectly fine.

Some example code is here:

```
            // Make sure to only match links to wikipedia with a rel tag
        $j('[role*="user-tooltip"][uid]').each(function()
        {
            // We make use of the .each() loop to gain access to each element via the "this" keyword...
            $j(this).qtip(
            {
                content: {
                    // Set the text to an image HTML string with the correct src URL to the loading image you want to use
                    text: '<div class="nexus-toolbar-spinner"></div>',
                    ajax: {
                        url: contextPath+'/users/profile-short.jsp', // Use the rel attribute of each element for the url to load
                        type: 'GET', // POST or GET
                        data: {targetUser: $j(this).attr('uid') }, // Data to pass along with your request
                        success: function(data, status) {

                            // Set the content manually (required!)
                            this.set('content.text', data);

                            //FB.XFBML.Host.refresh();

                            FB.XFBML.parse();

                        }
                    }

                },
                position: {
                    my: 'bottom center', // Position the tooltip above the link
                    at: 'top center',
                    viewport: $j(window), // Keep the tooltip on-screen at all times
                    effect: false, // Disable positioning animation
                    target: $j(this),
                    adjust: {
                        method: 'shift'
                    }

                },
                show: {
                    event: 'mouseover',
                    solo: true // Only show one tooltip at a time
                },
                hide: {
                      fixed: true,
                      delay: 500
                 },
                style: {
                    classes: 'ui-tooltip-wiki qtip-light qtip-shadow'
                }
            })
        });
```

On Firefox this displays the tooltip immediately below the item being hovered over.  However on Chrome and Safari the tooltip sometimes appears all the way at the bottom of the page, or even extends past the bottom of the page.

Comment: What do you mean by `the tool tip does not display properly on Webkit browsers` could you add a screenshot? Also could you add your css and the relevant htlm. It would be best if you create a small examples that reproduces your problem and put this sample on codepen.io or jsfiddle.